# rxjava - How to handle merge exceptions without terminating the whole process

Tags: exception, rx-java

I have created two observables.
One of them throws an exception.

```
obs1 = Observable.from(new Integer[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6});

obs2 = Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Integer>() {
    @Override public void call(Subscriber<? super Integer> subscriber) {
        boolean b = getObj().equals(""); // this throws an exception
        System.out.println("1");
    }
});
```

Now I invoke them using

```
Observable.merge(obs2, obs1)
          .subscribe(new Observer<Integer>() {
                @Override public void onCompleted() {
                    System.out.println("onCompleted");
                }

                @Override public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                    System.out.println("onError");
                }

                @Override public void onNext(Integer integer) {
                    System.out.println("onNext - " + integer);
                }
            });
```

Now, I dont want my process to halt completely when an exception occurs -
I want to handle it and I want obs1 to continue its work.

I have tried to write it using onErrorResumeNext(), onExceptionResumeNext(), doOnError()
but nothing helped - obs1 did not run.

How can I handle the exception without stopping the other observable from being processed?

Comment: Why not use `obs2.onErrorResumeNext(e -> Observable.empty())`?

Comment: This doesn't make obs1 run

Comment: So you want to ignore all errors of obs1 and obs2? However, the problem is if obs1 is a well-behavior Observable, it will terminate after emitting `onError`.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you need `mergeDelayError`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @nempoBu4 how do you know this is not the answer? The OP has two streams, one of it errors out and he wants to still receive values from the other. The de-facto operator in RxJava for this purpose is http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#mergeDelayError(rx.Observable)

Comment: «Sounds like» means that you are trying to guess, not to answer, so your answer has been flagged as `Low Quality`. But your comment is better suited for an answer. And it would be great if you add some examples to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your subscriber which is broken. You should catch your exception and call `onError`. Otherwise, you broke the rx contract.

example :

```
    Observable<Integer> obs1 = Observable.from(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6));

    Observable<Integer> obs2 = Observable.create((Subscriber<? super Integer> subscriber) -> {
        subscriber.onError(new NullPointerException());
    });

    Observable.merge(obs2.onErrorResumeNext((e) -> Observable.empty()), obs1)
            .subscribe(new Observer<Integer>() {
                @Override public void onCompleted() {
                    System.out.println("onCompleted");
                }

                @Override public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                    System.out.println("onError");
                }

                @Override public void onNext(Integer integer) {
                    System.out.println("onNext - " + integer);
                }
            });
```

so if you replace your `obs2` code with this, it should work like you expected :

```
obs2 = Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Integer>() {
    @Override public void call(Subscriber<? super Integer> subscriber) {
        try {

            boolean b = getObj().equals(""); // this throws an exception
            System.out.println("1");
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            subscriber.onError(ex);
        }
    }
});
```